# Prevent video from overdrawing window background

Tags: windows, winapi, ms-media-foundation

I have a 640x480 sized window. I want to put a 100x100 sized video in the top-left corner of that window. So I do:

```
RECT r;

r.left = 0;
r.top = 0;
r.right = 100;
r.bottom = 100;

m_pVideoDisplay->SetVideoPosition(NULL, &r);
```

This correctly puts the video in the top-left corner and scales it to 100x100 pixels but for some reason the Media Foundation video renderer will also fill all space in my window that is **not** occupied by the video with black now. How can I stop it from doing so? I've explicitly told the `IMFVideoDisplayControl` to only draw to the top-left 100x100 pixels of my window. But still it fills the remaining space of my window with black! What can I do to make Media Foundation not touch the rest of my window?

My `WM_PAINT` looks like this:

```
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);      
FillRect(ps.hdc, &rc, GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));         
m_pVideoDisplay->RepaintVideo();
EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

I'd expect all window space that is not occupied by the video to be white but it is black instead.

I've also tried to do this but it didn't help either:

```
m_pVideoDisplay->SetRenderingPrefs(MFVideoRenderPrefs_DoNotRenderBorder);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The code in the question does not help me to reproduce your problem. Please provide a reproducible code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the trick here is to simply add a child window to my parent window using `CreateWindowEx()` and have Media Foundation render to the child window instead of the parent by calling `SetVideoWindow()` of `IMFVideoDisplayControl`. Then there will be no more overdrawing and everything is fine. I don't even have to use `SetVideoPosition()` any longer because I can simply move the video around (or apply scaling) by calling the normal `MoveWindow()` Win32 API on the child window. This really works very smoothly.